# Could Motives aid in the study of the Navier-Stokes equations?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Recently, mathematicians and theoretical physicists have been studying Quantum Field Theory (and renormalization in particular) by means of abstract geometrical objects called [motives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motive_(algebraic_geometry)). Amongst these researchers are Marcolli, Connes, Kreimer (also working on the Hopf algebra approach) and Konsani. You can read about Marcolli's work [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=Jrix_1ORR6YC&printsec=frontcover&dq=feynman+motives&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=9YJ9T4znJoPs8QPTyJjZDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=feynman%20motives&f=false), and about the joint work by Connes and Marcolli [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=a6PdFik-a9QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=quantum+fields+and+motives&hl=en&sa=X&ei=er2CT5b-EMHU0QXThfH1Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quantum%20fields%20and%20motives&f=false).

Now, in the wikipedia article on the Navier-Stokes Equations, there is a short paragraph on Wyld Diagrams. It is stated there that they are similar to the Feynman diagrams studied in QFT. Since motives and other algebraic approaches are currently used to study these Feynman Diagrams, I was wondering if these approaches could also aid in studying the Wyld Diagrams, and therefore indirectly the Navier-Stokes equations.

If so, how? If not, why not?

Please note that I'm far from an expert in any of these fields, and that I have asked a similar [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27183/could-motives-aid-in-the-study-of-the-navier-stokes-equations) on the physics SE website.

Comment: What parts of the question are not covered by Willie Wong's comment and orbifold's answer on the other site?

Comment: @Didier orbifold mentioned himself that he wasn't an expert on this, so I posted this question just to be sure.